# Why different font are used by Safari on iPad and Mac

Tags: css, ios, macos

When I am loading our website in Safari (need Github authentication) : https://app.alpha-1.cloud.responsive.software/team/633ebdae942ada36567750b0

Look at `Responsive Test`

Have these settings:

```css
.breadcrumb-link {
    font-family: SFPro-Medium;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #c14953;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: SFPro-Medium;
    src: url(/fonts/SF-Pro.ttf);
    font-weight: medium;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

Mac:

[image]

iPad:

[image]

Comment: Problem was that instead of `font-family: SFPro-Medium;` `font-family: SFPro;` is needed.. And move up `@font-face` styles in css.

Answer (score 0):

Try to be as specific as possible:

1. specify the font format also (so "truetype")
2. specify the font-weight also in your css class

Different safari/browser versions can be more or less "forgiving" when it comes to `font-face` rules.

**css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: SFPro-Medium;
    src: url(/fonts/SF-Pro.ttf) format('truetype');
    font-weight: medium;
    font-display: swap;
}

.breadcrumb-link {
    font-family: SFPro-Medium;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #c14953;
    font-weight: medium;
}
```

**Common issues:**

Make sure your font is actually loaded via `@font-face` by checking the devtools network tab. You might actually see a **local version** in the first screenshot.
Try **numeric font-weight** values like `600` instead of `medium`.
Search for overriding css rules.